# Adding new column and set value from others column in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT Table1.proID, Table1.proName, Table1.price, Table1.amount, [gia]*[sl] AS total
FROM Table1;
```

How can I convert it to Linq ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var lst = Table1.Select(x => new { Filed1 = x.proID, Field2 = x.proName, Field3 =x.price,Field4 = x.amount, total=x.gia*x.sl});
```

Comment: new {}  will generate a new same type object ??

Comment: @Jackie It's a anonymous type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx